# Erro undefined method `sign_in_as!'

Tags: ruby

Estou com seguinte erro:

> Failure/Error: sign_in_as!(user) NoMethodError: undefined method
>   `sign_in_as!' for

[image: Estou com este error]

Alguém poderia me ajudar! Já adicionei o module, mas nada! Sou grato demais a todos que puderem me ajudar!
https://github.com/3IBit/ticketee

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei agora colocar o :type => :feature, mas não funcionou, saberia como faria no helper (module).
Sou iniciante ainda com BDD.
Sou grato a sua ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que o helper não esta carregado no seu teste.

Você precisa incluir eles no teste

Por exemplo:

```
class AuthenticationTest < ActionView::TestCase
  include AuthenticationHelper
end
```

Comment: Então, o problema que eu estou usando em módulo, como faria para chamar esse módulo?
ou o authenticationTest já é criado automaticamente e basta eu da include nele?

Comment: Dê o include no módulo

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui resolver! 
Na verdade eu usei um 
require 'support/authentication_helpers'
O teste passou! \o/
Mas obrigado novamente!

Comment: @RodolfoPeixoto, com o `include AuthenticationHelper` não deu certo?

Comment: Não funcionou! "/ , só quando chamei pelo require o arquivo que ele funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, efetuei o que havia me dito, porém o error persiste. Eu estou utilizando:

Arquivo:
authentication_helpers.rb

```
module AuthenticationHelpers
     def sign_in_as!(user)
         visit '/signin'
         fill_in "Name", with: user.name
         fill_in "Password", with: user.password
         click_button 'Sign in'
         expect(page).to have_content("Signed in successfully.")
     end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.include AuthenticationHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

O RSpec.configure do |c| ... ele não inclui em todo o teste?

O arquivo que estou efetuando o teste é o seguinte:
editing_tickets_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

require 'capybara/rails'

feature "Editing tickets" do

```
let!(:project) { FactoryGirl.create(:project) }
let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let!(:ticket) do
  ticket =  FactoryGirl.create(:ticket, project: project) 
  ticket.update(user: user)
  ticket
end

before do
    sign_in_as!(user)
    visit "/"
    click_link project.name
    click_link ticket.title
    click_link "Edit Ticket"
end

scenario "Updating a ticket" do
    fill_in "Title", with: "Make it really shiny!"
    click_button "Update Ticket"

    expect(page).to have_content "Ticket has been updated."

    within("#ticket h2") do
        expect(page).to have_content("Make it really shiny!")
    end

    expect(page).to_not have_content ticket.title
end

scenario "Updating a ticket with invalid information" do
    fill_in "Title", with: ""
    click_button "Update Ticket"

    expect(page).to have_content("Ticket has not been updated.")
end
```

end

já dei include e tentei colocar também o type: :feature feature e do before, mas nada! aparece sempre esse mesmo error:

```
rodolfopeixoto@rodolfopeixoto-3IBit:~/portifolio/projeto/rails/ticketee$ rspec spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb
```

FF

Failures:

1) Editing tickets Updating a ticket
     Failure/Error: sign_in_as!(user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in_as!' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::EditingTickets:0x007f199ed16e38>
     # ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:17:in`block (2 levels) in '

2) Editing tickets Updating a ticket with invalid information
     Failure/Error: sign_in_as!(user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in_as!' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::EditingTickets:0x007f199ef569a0>
     # ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:17:in`block (2 levels) in '

Finished in 0.04161 seconds (files took 1.52 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:24 # Editing tickets Updating a ticket
rspec ./spec/features/editing_tickets_spec.rb:37 # Editing tickets Updating a ticket with invalid information

Sou grato meu amigo.